# OKTA Self service registration with Nextjs REACT

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, okta, okta-signin-widget

I have been trying to allow users to sign up for my app with the Okta SSR feature however I keep getting this error that says:

```
{"errorCode":"E0000060","errorSummary":"Unsupported operation.","errorLink":"E0000060","errorId":"oaekKu3BL6EQv2antsdViFLZQ","errorCauses":[]}
```

In the console it says:

```
GET https://{devsite}.okta.com/api/v1/registration/form 501
```

Has anyone else had this issue for NextJS REACT? I have followed the setup guide **[here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/oie-embedded-sdk-use-case-self-reg/nodejs/main/)** twice. The login part of the custom widget works fine. just when clicking on sign up it will give the error and only show the custom brand stuff made for the widget. The code looks like this:

```
const oktaSignInConfig = {

  baseUrl: `https://${OKTA_DOMAIN}`,
  clientId: CLIENT_ID,
  logo: "/icons/TextLogo.svg",
  redirectUri: window.location.origin + "/login/callback",
  authParams: {
    // If your app is configured to use the Implicit Flow
    // instead of the Authorization Code with Proof of Code Key Exchange (PKCE)
    // you will need to uncomment the below line
    // pkce: false
  },
  registration: {
    parseSchema: (
      schema: any,
      onSuccess: (schema: any) => {},
      onFailure: (error: any) => {}
    ) => {
      // handle parseSchema callback
      schema.profileSchema.properties.primaryPhone = {
        'type': 'string',
        'description': 'Phone',
        'default': 'Enter your phone number'
      };
      schema.profileSchema.fieldOrder.push('primaryPhone');
      onSuccess(schema);
    },
    preSubmit: (
      postData: any,
      onSuccess: (postData: any) => {},
      onFailure: (error: any) => {}
    ) => {
      // handle preSubmit callback
      onSuccess(postData);
      const error = {
        errorSummary: "API Error",
        errorCauses: [
          {
            errorSummary: "Custom field level error",
            property: "userProfile.email",
          },
        ],
      };
      onFailure(error);
    },
    postSubmit: (
      response: any,
      onSuccess: (response: any) => {},
      onFailure: (error: any) => {}
    ) => {
      // handle postsubmit callback
      onSuccess(response);
      const error = {
        errorSummary: "API Error",
        errorCauses: [
          {
            errorSummary: "Custom field level error",
            property: "userProfile.email",
          },
        ],
      };
      onFailure(error);
    },
  },
  features: {
    registration: true,
    rememberMe: true,
    showPasswordToggleOnSignInPage: true,
  },
};
```

The registration part on the **[github](https://github.com/okta/okta-signin-widget#registration)** doesn't say anything about this error.

There are parts undocumented, if you go into the application section on Okta under the one you created and go to the assignments tab there is a little box that says **self service** and it is selected as **disabled** by default so naturally I had to enable it. Yet that did not fix the problem.

Then I tried going to the **Okta API scopes** tab and granting access to the registration it was **okta.clients.registration**. And that did not work.

The app I use is an OIDC for an SPA. I selected the top three check boxes for Grant type (Authorization code, interaction code, and refresh token) everything else is default. And I followed the article that I referenced earlier.

So, could anyone provide insight as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable registration in okta settings.

If you are using older version then check [this](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/set-up-self-service-registration/main/)

If you are up to date then you might have a look [here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/oie-embedded-sdk-use-case-self-reg/android/main/)

Comment: Hi! So the link you have given for the up to date article is what I have followed and results are still the same. I have already followed steps 1, 2, and 3. My app is up to date. I made it last week. Have you had this error before?

Comment: Hi @kpgabriel did you solve this issue? I am also getting the same problem. It would be helpful if you can comment how you solved this issue.

Comment: Hi @KiranB sorry, I was not able to solve this. We went with a different auth provider. In order to move past this blocker.